# Moodle User Selector

Tags: php, moodle

I'm talking about the User Selector with 2 columns and some arrows in the middle.

I tried to replicate what was in the /admin/roles/admins.php but with no success.

I found some interesting function in the lib.php of admin/roles that looks like this:

```
function core_role_get_potential_user_selector(context $context, $name, $options) {
$blockinsidecourse = false;
if ($context->contextlevel == CONTEXT_BLOCK) {
    $parentcontext = $context->get_parent_context();
    $blockinsidecourse = in_array($parentcontext->contextlevel, array(CONTEXT_MODULE, CONTEXT_COURSE));
}

if (($context->contextlevel == CONTEXT_MODULE || $blockinsidecourse) &&
        !is_inside_frontpage($context)) {
    $potentialuserselector = new core_role_potential_assignees_below_course('addselect', $options);
} else {
    $potentialuserselector = new core_role_potential_assignees_course_and_above('addselect', $options);
}

return $potentialuserselector;
```

}

I'm pretty much developing a local plugin where I want to bulk expire certificates of different users on a given course id.

Also, will I be able to do raw SQL UPDATE queries for the certificate update?

I'd appreciate some hints, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The key to replicate the user selectors of `admin/roles/admins.php` is to create two classes (one per "user list column") that extends `user_selector_base` (in admins.php you will find as examples `core_role_admins_existing_selector` and `core_role_admins_potential_selector`).

Basically you need to extend the base class `user_selector_base` and implement the `find_users` method as you see fit (depending of the type of user you want to show in the left and the right columns).

That method responsibility is to build a SQL query that selects users from the `user` table given a `$search` query (since the selector has a search input associated), but apart from that, the rest of what you do with the WHERE conditions depends of what you want to show in your lists (in the admins.php example you will find that they try to show the site admins filtering by site admins IDs).

This user selector class may be printed after instantiation and after the usual `$OUTPUT->header()` by calling `$selector->display();`.

Notice that the rest of the logic of `admins.php` is "controlled" independently of the user selectors, meaning that the user selectors by themselves are not responsible of the logic that transfers the users from one column to the other, they just print users and allows you to recover the information about which ones have been selected.

If you pay attention to `admins.php` you may notice that the original developer added some input submits (and confirmation steps) + optional params fetching, that eventually take care of adding/removing users of the admins list.

> I'm pretty much developing a local plugin where I want to bulk expire certificates of different users on a given course id.

In this case you may have to build the query for one column/user selector class with WHERE / JOIN that accounts for users with non expired certificates and the other column/user selector class accounting for the users with expired ones given a course id. This course id you may have to pass it as a param to your page from somewhere else (and then to the user selector classes) or else you will have to add a course selector to this page too.

> Also, will I be able to do raw SQL UPDATE queries for the certificate update?

Yes, you will have to write the logic to update the certificate expiration state, but depending of the certification plugin you are using it may be possible that some helper / API exists (you may want to check it before writing your own query).